# What is the easiest way to connect to a remote SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, setup, windows-server

So for the last few days I've been wrangling with usernames/passwords and trying to use different tools to connect, all to no avail.

I know there are many ways to connect, VPN, or command line, or SQL Server Management Studio.

What I've been doing normally is to use "Remote Desktop Connection" with Windows, but is that the best way?

What is the easiest way to do this?

My system specs are: 
Windows 7 Home premium

64-bit Op. System

I have "Shrew soft VPN access mgr"

I then use "Remote Desktop Connection" (on windows)

Then I land on a remote machine with these specs(when I use another user's credentials that work):

"Windows server 2008 r2 std"

64-bit OS

.. etc ( do you want the Computer name, domain, and workgroup settings ?)

Comment: What type of server is it?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg - I'm not sure how to answer.. I mean, it runs MSSQL . So windows/MS type server i'd say

Comment: What exactly are the errors that you're receiving when trying to connect with the tools you mention. And what parameters are you using when you're connecting?

Comment: @Adel You should [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/464972/edit) your question to mention what version of Windows and what database server you are using, along with that version as well. It will help people answer it properly

Comment: Your question is not clear, but I am guessing you are trying to access a sql database across a network. If so, then the first thing you need to do is make sure that the SQL Server service is configured to allow remote access. By default this is disabled (at least for recent versions of SQL). The precise method of configuring this depends on the version of Sql server. Then you need to make sure that your firewall is configured to allow Sql traffic through.

Comment: I'd recommend SQL Server Management Studio. Remote Desktop is overkill for just connecting to a database.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use one of the following:

- [**SQuirrlL**](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/)
- [**Toad For SQL Server**](http://toadforsqlserver.com)

Comment: What about for MS-SQL ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Install it on your desktop.

You may need to enable remote admin connections on the SQL Server end.

```
exec sp_configure 'remote admin connections', 1
go
reconfigure
go
```

Are both computers at work? Or is one at home and the other at work? If so, then you will need to use a VPN to connect to your work network. However, once that is done, you still just use SSMS from your desktop.